# React - File upload progress for an each one

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-dropzone

I`m running into a problem related with file uploading. I`m making a Dropzone component based on react-dropzone library. I need to upload files and show upload progress for an each one. Moreover I want to keep my uploaded files(with a result) in zone and delete only by user click.

This is my return statement.

```
return (
    <Container {...getRootProps({ isDragActive, isDragAccept, isDragReject })}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      {filesToRender || (
        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
```

After I drag some file into the zone it calls this function:

```
 const onDrop =  acceptedFiles => {
    for (const file of acceptedFiles) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", file);
       axios.post(`http://localhost:8080/files`, formData, {
        headers: {
          Authorization:
            "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJmb28iLCJleHAiOjE1ODIxNzc2NjAsImlhdCI6MTU4MjE0MTY2MH0.CWtDOIrFoitXHDeXCha0mT3HVyvTrwg8nXhsNaLkZVs"
        },
        onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
          const percentCompleted = Math.round(
            (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
          );
          file.progress = percentCompleted;
          // set progress for an each file
        }
      });
    }
    setFiles([...files, ...acceptedFiles]);
  };
```

**I want to setFiles and then somehow change it during the uploading**.

My **filesToRender**:

```
const filesToRender =
    files.length &&
    files.map((file, index) => {
      return (
        <File key={index}>
          <FileInfo>
            {file.name}
            {file.progress} //get progress from an each file object
          </FileInfo>
          <Button onClick={event => removeFile(event, index)}>
            Убрать файл
          </Button>
        </File>
      );
    });
```

How can I do that? setFiles is async, so I have problems with reseting it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the state after the progress updates:

```js
const onDrop = (acceptedFiles) => {
    acceptedFiles.map((file, index) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);
        axios.post(`http://localhost:8080/files`, formData, {
            headers: {
                Authorization:
                    "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJmb28iLCJleHAiOjE1ODIxNzc2NjAsImlhdCI6MTU4MjE0MTY2MH0.CWtDOIrFoitXHDeXCha0mT3HVyvTrwg8nXhsNaLkZVs",
            },
            onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                const percentCompleted = Math.round(
                    (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
                );
                file.progress = percentCompleted;
                // set progress for an each file

                setFiles((prevFiles) => {
                    if (prevFiles[index]) {
                        prevFiles[index] = file;
                    }

                    return [...prevFiles];
                });             
            },
        });
    });

    setFiles([...files, ...acceptedFiles]);
};
```